# How to compare decimal values of two properties of a document in an Elasticsearch query with Nest?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have documents typed product indexed in elasticsearch index.

These product documents have 2 decimal values: `NormalPrice`, `DiscountPrice`.

I want to search documents which have `NormalPrice > DiscountPrice`.

I tried to construct a query like this:

```
q &= Query<ProductModel>.Range(u => u.Field(f => f.NormalPrice).GreaterThan(u.Field(f => f.DiscountPrice)));
```

First of all I'm not sure if my query is correct but if it is, `GreaterThan` function requires double values as I see.

What should I do? Is there an alternative way of doing this comparison with decimal values?

BTW changing property types to double is not an option. I have to use decimal.

Comment: @RussCam I see you as my elasticsearch teacher, I don't know how to thank you these days. If you have idea - I bet you have - about this question too, can you please help me once again :-) btw I will ask you - if I may - some more questions to you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Elasticsearch supports `long`, `integer`, `short`, `byte`, `double` and `float` numeric data types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/number.html), so NEST maps `decimal` types to `double` by default.

To perform a comparison across document fields can be achieved with a [`script` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/script-query-usage.html)

```
client.Search<ProductModel>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Script(sn => sn
            .Inline("doc['normalPrice'].value > doc['discountPrice'].value")
        )
    )
);
```

Bear in mind that `script` queries can be expensive and potentially much slower than other queries depending on what you're doing. If this is a query that you need to run a lot, you might consider storing the comparison as a boolean field in the document and setting it up as a Property on your `ProductModel` type

```
public class ProductModel
{
    public decimal NormalPrice { get; set:}
    public decimal DiscountPrice { get; set:}
    public bool NormalPriceGreaterThanDiscountPrice 
    { 
        get { return NormalPrice > DiscountPrice; } 
    }
}
```

and then querying on that.